# define Code Contracts on Func<>

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am trying to integrate [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) into some existing code and so far so good for the most part.  The problem I am facing though is that I have set up contracts on an interface and one implementation delegates the implementation to a Func<> that is passed into the constructor of the class similar to the following:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IFooContract))]
public interface IFoo
{
    object Bar();
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFoo))]
public abstract class IFooContract : IFoo
{
    object IFoo.Bar()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() != null);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DelegatedFoo : IFoo
{
    public DelegatedFoo(Func<object> barImplementation)
    {
        Contract.Requires(barImplementation != null);
        _barImplementation = barImplementation;
    }
    private readonly Func<object> _barImplementation;

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_barImplementation != null);
    }

    public object Bar()
    {
        //"ensures unproven: Contract.Result<object>() != null" here.
        return _barImplementation();
    }
}
```

The static analyser reports the error "ensures unproven: Contract.Result() != null".  Can I define contracts on Func<> (and by extension on Action<>)?

Is this the best solution?

```
public class DelegatedFoo : IFoo
{
    public DelegatedFoo(Func<object> barImplementation)
    {
        Contract.Requires(barImplementation != null);
        _barImplementation = barImplementation;
    }
    private readonly Func<object> _barImplementation;

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ObjectInvariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_barImplementation != null);
    }

    public object Bar()
    {
        var result = _barImplementation();
        Contract.Assume(result != null);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, will you *always* have control over the `Func<object>` instance passed in? If so, every function referenced by the `Func<object>` parameter will need to have a `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() != null)` postcondition defined.

The same would be true if you had an `Action` parameter, instead.

Also, I most definitely would not use `Contract.Assume(result != null)`. Are you sure you'll never return null? What would happen if you did? Try changing that to `Contract.Assert(result != null)` instead. If you have control over the `Func<object>` parameter and use postconditions, then you should be able to also specify a postcondition on the `public object Bar()` method and forego the need for any asserts or assumptions.

Lastly, you may want to consider adding `Contract.Ensures(_barImplementation == barImplementation)` to your constructor of `DelegatedFoo`, though, I suppose that the postcondition is covered by the defined invariants. I always like to be explicit—it most certainly can't hurt, especially where the static analyzer is concerned.